# MySQL resultset

Tags: mysql, performance, resultset, overhead

I have a question regarding the resultset that came from the server.  Is there any way to DONT receive the very large stuff of field names and metadata, even if I make a prep.statement and bind etc. the return is very large with my actual data of 15% rest i col names etc.

I don't understand the fact of receiving columnname s of the result set when I have made a binding.
The smartest way should of course be that the resultset was in the form of stmthandle + offset of date, because the client already now how to bind.

This is very weird, or did I missed something?

Comment: Hmm,  So:  "Is there any way to DONT receive the very large stuff of field names and metadata" isn´t a real question. Of course I can be cleare to ask: Is there a way to shutoff the return of metadata when use "hard" binding ala ODBC. But Jan below answered my question. Thanks Jan.

Answer (score 2):

The resultset metadata is always returned with the resultset. No, there's no way to turn that off.

The metadata is only one part of the "overhead" associated with SQL queries.

That overhead is a big part of why it's "more efficient" to run a single query to get the set of data you need, rather than executing multiple statements.